# NSDecimal equal to NSDecimalNumber value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber, nsdecimal

I am looking for an effective way to save `NSDecimalNumber` with other data in `NSData` buffer.

I have not found a method to do it directly from `NSDecimalNumber`.
However, it is easy to convert it with :

```
NSDecimal value = [theDecimalNumber decimalValue];
```

And it is not difficult to transfer `NSDecimal` in memory (20 bytes).

But, my question: **The `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSDecimal` values are they exactly the same?**

Because their declarations have some differences (`ExternalRefCount` ?):

```
@interface NSDecimalNumber : NSNumber {
@private
    signed   int _exponent:8;
    unsigned int _length:4;
    unsigned int _isNegative:1;
    unsigned int _isCompact:1;
    unsigned int _reserved:1;
    unsigned int _hasExternalRefCount:1;
    unsigned int _refs:16;
    unsigned short _mantissa[0]; /* GCC */
}

typedef struct {
    signed   int _exponent:8;
    unsigned int _length:4;     // length == 0 && isNegative -> NaN
    unsigned int _isNegative:1;
    unsigned int _isCompact:1;
    unsigned int _reserved:18;
    unsigned short _mantissa[NSDecimalMaxSize];
} NSDecimal;
```

Is it possible to perform many transfers between the two type, without any loss of precision ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made numerous calculations with the transfer from one to the other without any problems.
So I think we can say that they are suitable as identical.

I extend `NSDecimalNumber` with :

```
#define DecNum_SizeOf   20

+ (NSDecimalNumber *) fromPtr:(void *)ptr
{
    NSDecimal valueRead;
    memcpy (&valueRead, ptr, DecNum_SizeOf);
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:valueRead];
}

- (void) toPtr:(void *)ptr
{
    NSDecimal valueWrite = [self decimalValue];
    memcpy (ptr, &valueWrite, DecNum_SizeOf);
}
```

While awaiting a method more "standard" to perform the job as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `NSArchiver` class methods?

```
NSData *data=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourNumber];
```

Comment: Yes. On iOS there is no NSArchiver, but only NSKeyedArchiver (?) And data.length == 451 to 458 bytes !!! vs 20 for NSDecimal...